# How to get error state from simple_strtol()? (converting string to int in C)

Tags: c, linux

I want to parse an `int` from a `string` (`char*`) in C. I'm writing a linux kernel module for embedded linux. I'm trying to use `simple_strtol` found [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-simple-strtol.html).

My tokens I'm parsing in an ideal situation will be numbers. The problem I have is `"0"` is a valid input. `strtol` returns `0` if a value could not be parsed (error). So that means that the following code:

```
char* token = "should_fail";

char **endptr;
char value = simple_strtol(token, endptr, 10); // 10 is the base to convert to
if (!**endptr){
    printf("failed!");
} else {
    printf(value);
}

char* token = "0"; // should pass
char **endptr;
char value = simple_strtol(token, endptr, 10); // 10 is the base to convert to
if (!**endptr){
    printf("failed!");
} else {
    printf(value);
}
```

prints out `0` in both cases, when it should fail in the first case. I am trying to use that `*endptr` argument to check to see if the conversion is successful, but its not working. According to what I've researched, `*endptr` is "A pointer to the end of the parsed string will be placed here". And I believe if a conversion failed the pointer will point to nothing so I can identify that failure.

Does anybody know how I can parse `"0"` properly and get a return value of `0` while still identifying a failed parse, and not having it return `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not create a pointer-to-pointer variable for `endptr`. Instead declare a single pointer, and pass the address of that with the unary `&` operator:

```
char *endptr;

simple_strtol(token, &endptr, 10);

if (endptr == NULL) ...
```

---

I didn't read the manual page but basically copied what the OP had used. Froom the [manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html):

> If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no conversion is performed; the value of str is stored in the object pointed to by endptr, provided that endptr is not a null pointer.

This means that if `strtol` (or your alternative if it's working as specified) returns `0` *and* `endptr == token` then the string was invalid.

So the check should be

```
if (value == 0 && endptr == token)
{
    /* String is not a valid number */
}
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and it did not work. `if (endptr == NULL)` and `if (!endptr)` do not evaluate to true even if the token is a string of invalid non parse-able characters like `soidfj`.

Comment: @unexpected62 I didn't read the manual page on how to check for illegal numbers. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: After googling more I also tried if `(*endptr == NULL)` and if `(*!endptr)` and those do not evaluate to true either.

Comment: I prefer the check '`if (endptr != token && *endptr == '\0')`' which verifies that the entire string was processed.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I appreciate the link to the manual page as well.